# How to append a node to the beginning of xml using Groovy

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

So I'm using groovy to modify an xml file and this is where I am:

Input:

```
<parentNode>
 <childNode version="4"/>
 <childNode version="3"/>
 <childNode version="2"/>
 <childNode version="1"/>
</parentNode>
```

I want to add a new `childNode` for version 5 such that it appears on the top

The expected output:

```
<parentNode>
  <childNode version="5"/>
  <childNode version="4"/>
  <childNode version="3"/>
  <childNode version="2"/>
  <childNode version="1"/>
</parentNode>
```

Currently, my code is appending it at the bottom.

The current (incorrect) output:

```
<parentNode>
  <childNode version="4"/>
  <childNode version="3"/>
  <childNode version="2"/>
  <childNode version="1"/>
  <childNode version="5"/>
</parentNode>
```

I'm using XmlParser for this and this is my code:

```
def xmlFile = "input.xml"
def parent = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)  

def new_child = new NodeBuilder().childNode(version: "5")
parent.append(new_child)

def nodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.xml"))) 
nodePrinter.preserveWhitespace = true 
nodePrinter.print(document)
```

Any thoughts on how I can append it at the top?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
myXmlString = '''<parentNode>
  <childNode version="4"/>
  <childNode version="3"/>
  <childNode version="2"/>
  <childNode version="1"/>
</parentNode>'''

// using parseText() because I have it here as text but for you it is probably parse()
def newXml = new XmlParser( false, true ).parseText( myXmlString )

newValue = "  <childNode version=\"5\"/>"
newNode = new XmlParser( false, true ).parseText( newValue )

newXml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'parentNode' }.children().add( 0, newNode ) // 0 == position

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( newXml )
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><parentNode>
  <childNode version="5"/>
  <childNode version="4"/>
  <childNode version="3"/>
  <childNode version="2"/>
  <childNode version="1"/>
</parentNode>
```

It adds the xml prologue, if you don't want it, remove with:

```
.replaceAll('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '')
```

Comment: What is the meaning of '**' here? I ask because the solution is not working for me and I suspect it has something to with the fact that my actual document is actually structured differently. <parentNode> is a child of a <rootNode>:
<rootNode>
  <parentNode>
    <childNode....

Comment: It is the same as `.depthFirst()` you can read about it [here](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_flexible_navigation_with_children_depthfirst_and_breadthfirst)

Answer (score 1):

More or less same [answer as @ou_ryperd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63157658/1449839), but without modifying too much the OP's code:

Replace

```
parent.append(new_child)
```

by

```
parent.children().add(0, new_child)
```

It should work as you wanted.
Just be sure to get the proper `parent` node if it's not actually the root.